# join multiple columns values of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, oracle, join, where-clause

i need to join the values of multiple columns from multiple tables

ex

```
userid        username         answeredquestion1 answeredquestion2
1                aa                       1             1
2                bb                       1              0
```

i need result as

```
userid          username        question name           response
1                 aa             answertoquestion1         1   
2                 bb             answertoquestion2         0
```

if the value is `null` it should not copy the data from the first table

i used the following command but its not working

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN AnswerToQuestion1 > 0 --and userid not in  (Select Userid from b) --and AnswerToQuestion1 not in (Select AnswerToQuestion from b) 
THEN
INTO b (userid, username, AnswerToQuestion) VALUES (UserID, UserName, AnswerToQuestion1)
WHEN AnswerToQuestion2 > 0 --and userid not in  (Select Userid from b) --and AnswerToQuestion2 not in (Select AnswerToQuestion from b) 
THEN
INTO b (userid, username, AnswerToQuestion) VALUES (UserID, UserName, AnswerToQuestion2) 
WHEN AnswerToQuestion3 > 0 --and userid not in  (Select Userid from b) --and AnswerToQuestion3 not in (Select AnswerToQuestion from b) 
THEN
INTO b (userid, username, AnswerToQuestion) VALUES (UserID, UserName, AnswerToQuestion3) 
SELECT UserID, UserName, AnswerToQuestion1, AnswerToQuestion2, AnswerToQuestion3 
FROM a
where not exists (SELECT userid, ANSWERTOQUESTION  FROM b where b.userid=a.userid and 
a.ANSWERTOQUESTION2 = b.ANSWERTOQUESTION)
```

(or)

```
insert into b 
(select userID,username,AnswerToQuestion2 as AnswerToQuestion from a  where 
union all
select userID,username,AnswerToQuestion1 as AnswerToQuestion from a)
```

This one will repeat the datas that means the duplicate values repeating

the condition i need to satisfy is it need to check 4 columns in the first table and 3 columns in the second table.
can anyone suggest me the solution

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this mysql, oracle or Sql Server? `INSERT ALL WHEN` is not SQL Server syntax, but others will need to know what they're dealing with. They are all different data engines.

Comment: @yogesh. Kindly update the tag properly, so that we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you can use `MERGE` using an `UNPIVOT` statement in the `USING` subquery:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/163b7/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  userid            INTEGER,
  username          VARCHAR2(20),
  answeredquestion1 NUMBER(1,0),
  answeredquestion2 NUMBER(1,0)
);

INSERT INTO A
SELECT 1, 'aa', 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'bb', 1, 0 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE B (
  userid        INTEGER,
  username      VARCHAR2(20),
  question_name VARCHAR2(20),
  response      NUMBER(1,0)
);

MERGE INTO B dst
USING (
  SELECT userid, username, question_name, response
  FROM   A
  UNPIVOT (
    response
    FOR question_name IN (
      answeredquestion1 AS 'answertoquestion1',
      answeredquestion2 AS 'answertoquestion2'
    )
  )
) src
ON ( src.userid = dst.userid AND src.question_name = dst.question_name )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( userid, username, question_name, response )
  VALUES ( src.userid, src.username, src.question_name, src.response );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   B
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/163b7/1/0)**:

```
| USERID | USERNAME |     QUESTION_NAME | RESPONSE |
|--------|----------|-------------------|----------|
|      2 |       bb | answertoquestion1 |        1 |
|      2 |       bb | answertoquestion2 |        0 |
|      1 |       aa | answertoquestion1 |        1 |
|      1 |       aa | answertoquestion2 |        1 |
```

Comment: THANKS, its working fine. but how to avoid the null values?

Comment: also how to override the response values from 0 to 1